# PHP IRC bot not responding to commands

Tags: php, irc

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$sock = fsockopen("localhost", 6667);
fwrite($sock, "NICK PHP_thang\r\n");
fwrite($sock, "USER fikeh fikeh fikeh :Fikeh's Thang\r\n");
fwrite($sock, "JOIN #LightSpike\r\n");

while (True) {
        echo fgets($sock);
        if (strpos(fgets($sock), "!about")) {
                fwrite($sock, "PRIVMSG #LightSpike :\x02Fike's PHP Bot:\x02 Fike's test bot.\r\n");
        }
}
?>
```

Basically, it looks through the lines received from the socket and if it finds "!about", it writes a message to the channel. But it doesn't. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: 2 things for you... 1) Accept some of your previous answers if you want help 2) post more code so we can see what is going on please

Comment: Sorry, I forget to accept answers. I'll post more code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the stream with `echo fgets($sock);` which clears the stream. When the execution gets to the conditional next line, `fgets( $sock )` is empty. Either remove the echo line or put the contents to a variable first:

```
while (True) {
    $buffer = fgets( $sock );
    echo $buffer;
    if( strpos( $buffer, "!about" ) !== false ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also note that `strpos()` returns `0` if the search string is at the start of the line and `0 == false`. With `strpos()` you should always use `strpos( $needle, $haystack ) === false` (or `!== false`).

Comment: While you're definitely right about `strpos` (this is a common pitfall), I'd like to note that it doesn't actually matter in this situation since because of protocol rules the response line cannot start with `!about` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `fgets` will read a single line from the socket, but that line is only read *once*. The next time you call `fgets` again, the next line will be read. So, you should read the line in a variable, then only do stuff with the variable. The way you've set it up now, half of the server responses will be `echo`'d, and half will be checked for the `!about` command.